# How to use lodash's _sortBy() to alphabetically sort this list with a custom requirement?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following array of objects:

```
const myList = [
  { id: 1, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant' },
  { id: 2, title: '[P] Sinus Pain - M' },
  { id: 3, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant' },
  { id: 4, title: 'Check up male' },
  { id: 5, title: '[A] Animal Bite - M' },
  { id: 6, title: 'Duration' },
  { id: 7, title: '[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant' },
  { id: 8, title: '[P] Skin Injury - M' },
  { id: 9, title: 'Emergency Screening' }
]
```

After doing:

```
_.sortBy(myList, 'title');
```

I get:

```
Check up male
Duration
Emergency Screening
[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant
[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant
[A] Animal Bite - M
[P] Sinus Pain - M
[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant
[P] Skin Injury - M
```

It looks good except I want the items without [A] or [P] to be at the bottom instead of the top. So like this instead:

```
[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant
[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant
[A] Animal Bite - M
[P] Sinus Pain - M
[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant
[P] Skin Injury - M
Check up male
Duration
Emergency Screening
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`localeCompare`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with `numeric: false` option in the sort function:

```js
const list = [ { id: 1, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant' }, { id: 2, title: '[P] Sinus Pain - M' }, { id: 3, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant' }, { id: 4, title: 'Check up male' }, { id: 5, title: '[A] Animal Bite - M' }, { id: 6, title: 'Duration' }, { id: 7, title: '[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant' }, { id: 8, title: '[P] Skin Injury - M' }, { id: 9, title: 'Emergency Screening' } ] 

const r = list.sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title, 0, {numeric: false}))

console.log(r)
```

Another way you can also get the same result is via the `{caseFirst: lower'}` option parameter as noted (and explained) by `@xehpuk` asnwer:

```js
const list = [ { id: 1, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant' }, { id: 2, title: '[P] Sinus Pain - M' }, { id: 3, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant' }, { id: 4, title: 'Check up male' }, { id: 5, title: '[A] Animal Bite - M' }, { id: 6, title: 'Duration' }, { id: 7, title: '[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant' }, { id: 8, title: '[P] Skin Injury - M' }, { id: 9, title: 'Emergency Screening' } ] 

const r = list.sort((a,b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title, 0, {caseFirst: 'lower'}))

console.log(r)
```

You also do not need lodash for this if **ES6** is an option.

Answer (score 4):

lodash's [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortBy) may take list of comparators. So you can just declare "words don't start from square bracket go later" and inside the "group" sort by title

```
_.sortBy(myList, [
    item => !item.title.startsWith("["), 
    'title'
]);
```

And with [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy) you even can specify ordering in more readable(and flexible) way:

```
_.orderBy(myList, [
    item => item.title.startsWith("["), 
    'title'
], ['desc', 'asc']);
```

[UPD] with `startsWith` mentioned by @Ele it looks even better

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use lodash, you can compare the titles in lower-case:

```
_.sortBy(myList, item => item.title.toLowerCase());
```

This works because the code unit of the lower-case characters (97 - 122) is greater than the one of `[` (91). This would also have the benefit of comparing the titles case-insensitively.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative using the function [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Assuming the there is max one `[` in the string.

```js
const myList = [  { id: 1, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant' },  { id: 2, title: '[P] Sinus Pain - M' },  { id: 3, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant' },  { id: 4, title: 'Check up male' },  { id: 5, title: '[A] Animal Bite - M' },  { id: 6, title: 'Duration' },  { id: 7, title: '[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant' },  { id: 8, title: '[P] Skin Injury - M' },  { id: 9, title: 'Emergency Screening' }];

myList.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.title.startsWith("[") && b.title.startsWith("[")) {
    return a.title.substring(1).localeCompare(b.title.substring(1)); 
  } 
  
  return a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
});

console.log(myList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your comparator doesn't sort the titles not starting with `[`. It just moves them to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the brackets parts to top by checking the strings, then takes the local compare result.

```js
const
    startsWithBrackets = s => /^\[.+\]/.test(s),
    myList = [{ id: 1, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Not Pregnant' }, { id: 2, title: '[P] Sinus Pain - M' }, { id: 3, title: '[A] Animal Bite - F - Pregnant' }, { id: 4, title: 'Check up male' }, { id: 5, title: '[A] Animal Bite - M' }, { id: 6, title: 'Duration' }, { id: 7, title: '[P] Skin Injury - F - Not Pregnant' }, { id: 8, title: '[P] Skin Injury - M' }, { id: 9, title: 'Emergency Screening' }];

myList.sort(({ title: a }, { title: b }) =>
    startsWithBrackets(b) - startsWithBrackets(a) || a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(myList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```